# InnoDB: Assertion failure in file .../padding_for_CPACK_RPM_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS_PREFIX/mariadb-10.4.13/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 7940

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Every hour one MariaDB version 10.4 database stops responding and I see this output in the log file:

```
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: 2023-02-09 10:00:02 0x7f72547a5700  InnoDB: Assertion failure in file /home/buildbot/buildbot/padding_for_CPACK_RPM_BUILD_SOURCE_DIRS_PREFIX/mariadb-10.4.13/storage/innobase/btr/btr0cur.cc line 7940
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: Failing assertion: space_id == page_get_space_id(page)
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to https://jira.mariadb.org/
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/innodb-recovery-modes/
Feb  9 10:00:02 maria55 mysqld: InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

The server is running Kopano and although I can't find any prominent CRONs that cause this problem exactly on the hour, I fully suspect Kopano has some maintenance routines every hour triggering the crash.

The advice about corruption in InnoDB sounds legitimate, but I don't know how to do that the links are not clear.

For now we did a `mysqlcheck kopano` and database checks works 100%

Googling further doesn't really show anything.

I'm at a loss what to try next.

My one idea is to upgrade the database to see if any 'bugs' might be squashed, but when we did a dump to the same disk, this happened:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --routines kopano -r kopanodb.sql

mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table 'lob' at row: 166961
```

Now I have a secondary problem in that I can't make a backup. The total size of the database is 80GB!

My idea was to upgrade MariaDB but now I am scared things go catastrophically wrong and I won't have a good backup.

My other idea was to maybe stop the MariaDB service and then copy `/var/lib/mysql` to a temporary location, all 80 GB, and then at least maybe this will be an okay backup.

Any other ideas or tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to do a MariaDB upgrade. The clues were version 10.4 of MariaDB is very old, and this line:

> Submit a detailed bug report...

To get around the problem of database backup, I took the database offline by stopping the service, and then just did a directory/file copy. It's not an ideal backup but I think I would have been able to restore had something gone wrong.